# Invalid path error in DSpace query - 'ıtem.metadata'

Tags: java, postgresql, dspace

I'm encountering an "Invalid path" error while executing a query in DSpace. The error message specifically points to the path 'ıtem.metadata'. However, I believe the correct path should be 'item.metadata'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sANTF.png)

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and execute the query successfully. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it looks like it should be `item` and not `ıtem`, but what is your actual question? Where does that query come from?

Comment: When I visit the URL "http://localhost:8080/xmlui/submissions," I receive the following error message: "Invalid path: 'ıtem.metadata' [SELECT item FROM org.dspace.content.Item as item left join ıtem.metadata dc_date_accessioned WITH dc_date_accessioned.metadataField.id = :dc_date_accessioned WHERE item.inArchive = :in_archive AND item.submitter =:submitter ORDER BY STR(dc_date_accessioned.value) desc]."

I'm not sure which file this query is coming from, and I'm looking for assistance on resolving this issue